# Matlab: how to trasform the double value [] in a char ''

Tags: char, double, cell

I have this array and I want to trasform the value double [] in a char ''

```
 A={[];[];'1';[];[];'3';'2';'2';'2';'3';'3';[];'2';'2';'4';'4';'2';'3';[];[];[];'1';'1';'1';'1';'1';'3';'3';'3';'3';'3';'3';'4';'4';'4';'4';[];[];[];[];[]};
```

I have try to use

```
if A==[]
A='';
end
```

but Matlab gives this error: `'Undefined function 'eq' for input arguments of type 'cell'. '`
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a cell array, you don't have a choice but to loop through every entry in the cell array to replace those empty values with the empty string.  Using the `if` statement that way does not work as you expect.  I suggest you spend time reading a MATLAB tutorial before asking more questions.

Regardless, you can do something like this:

```
for ii = 1 : numel(A)
    if(isempty(A{ii}))
        A{ii} = '';
    end
end
```

[`isempty`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isempty.html) checks to see if a matrix is empty. We check each cell for this case and if it is, replace the cell's contents with the empty string.